# xperf profiling mixed mode code won't show native functions

Tags: c++, dll, profiling, mixed-mode, xperf

I'm profiling part of my application using Visual Studio 2012, it's a dll containing native C++ and .net C++/CLI managed code. The performance report nicely shows information for all my managed code, but any place the managed code calls into native code, I can't dig down, only get [Unknown] shown as the location.
 I *really* need to profile the native code, that's where the bulk of the functionality lies.

Comment: [*Here's a method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), and [*here's a video*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: That is very random, but in this case it actually worked Mike. Thanks. Not so applicable with a function utilizing only 0.1% CPU though. Question still valid.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I only worry about big stuff. Each thing I fix reduces the total time, which is the denominator in the fraction of time taken by other things. Do this several times, and what was originally 0.1% can ultimately become 10% or more.